# SVN diff command - ignore BOM

Tags: svn, diff, ignore, byte-order-mark

I'm using SVN in order to commit changes in windows and linux, but when I want to commit changes in some cases a BOM characters is added/ remove from files.
I want that the diff of SVN will ignore this changes with BOM and will show me only the files I have changed.
Do you know a diff command that will ignore BOM characters?

thanks.

Comment: I've deleted my (non-)answer ; but I insist : a BOM added to one of your files is actually a change -- and can have some impact on the way your code runs ; you should configure your IDE/editor so it doesn't add a BOM.

Comment: how can I configure my visual studio to do not add a BOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you didn't mention what platform you are on, but if you are on Windows, [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) has pretty good handling of BOM and can be integrated with SVN.

Comment: WinMerge understands and ignores the BOM too, the problem is that SVN marks the file as dirty and you have to use a compare tool to see that nothing (but the BOM) is changed.

Answer (score 4):

You should rather configure your editors not to emit a BOM character. If you're using a proper encoding (UTF-8), it's neither needed nor useful.